# show UTC+7 instead of GMT+7 when formating using date-fns-tnz

Tags: date-fns, moment-timezone

I used to format timezone using moment-timezone and I use `tz().format()` and got result `04:25PM UTC+07:00` now it turn my friend move from moment-timezone to date-fns, im trying to achieve what i achieve using moment-timezone, but what i get is in GMT formatted like this `04:25 PM GMT+7`

I have read the documentation of date-fns but i could not find format the date to UTC+7

this is code I have tried

```
formatInTimeZone('2022-09-12T09:25:19.789Z', 'Asia/Bangkok', 'hh:mm a zzz')

format( utcToZonedTime('2022-09-12T09:25:19.789Z', 'Asia/Bangkok'), 'hh:mm a zzz',{ timeZone: 'UTC' })
```

i still could not get like `04:25PM UTC+07:00`

what i expected is `04:25PM UTC+07:00`

what i got is `04:25 PM GMT+7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can use this instead , add manually +800

```
 const TIME_FORMAT_24 = 'HH:mm a +0800';
format(
        utcToZonedTime(new Date(), timezone),
        TIME_FORMAT
      );
```

Comment: yeah i think this one is good answer